# set components visible property on a panel or form

Tags: delphi

How to grab all components from a form or a panel and set the visible property to false ?

```
   ///  
   ///    loop all components, this is just an idea for the solution ,,,,
   ///

   for i:= 0 to myPanel.ComponentsList do
        begin

        ///

        MyComponent.visible := false; 


        end;
```

Comment: using Delphi 2010 and Delphi XE3

Comment: TPanel.Visible := False will do the job perfectly (ok, also hiding itself) :o)

Comment: @ken like I do in my answer. ;)

Comment: Got it. I thought `Visible` was `published` further down in the hierarchy, but I see it's in TControl. @jachguate: I've written the same code in dozens of answers here. :-) I just didn't think `Visible` was *visible* (pun intended) that high up in the inheritance tree. :-)

Comment: I don't understand - why not just make the panel invisible and let all its child controls disappear with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [Controls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.Controls) array for that purpose.

For example:

```
for I := 0 to Panel1.ControlCount - 1 do
  Panel1.Controls[I].Visible := False;
```